# Filter URL in Google Analytics

Tags: php, url, google-analytics

I am a beginner of using google analytics api, and i have a problem with filter pattern.

I want to track page view of all businesses detail page from yesterday to today. Url for one business have format: 
business/[business-name]/[business-id].

Here is my code for tracking page view of businesses detail page

```
$lastDay = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime('today') - 24*3600));
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$client = new Google_Client();
//get ga_client_id,ga_email_address,get key
.....
//declare metrics, dimensions,filter pattern
$metrics = 'ga:pageviews';
$articlePattern = '/business/[a-zA_Z0-9_-]+/id-[a-f0-9]';
$optParamsArticles = array(
  'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath,ga:date',
  'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
  'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=~' . $articlePattern
);
$businessResults = $analytics->data_ga->get( $analytics_id,
   $lastDay,
   $today,
   $metrics,
   $optParamsArticles
)
```

The problem happen when user use  url have format: business/[business-name]/[business-id]?params=vals. Google behave above  url is a other request and then return this link with page view = 1 . We have about 5000 business, and each of business have 24  urls have format with the same format  of this url(business/[business-name]/business-id?params=a ; business/[business-name]/business-id?params=b,...). But max-result parameter of data_ga->get is 10000.

So we need to "group by" 24 urls business/[business-name]/[business-id] ?params=vals to 1 url : business/[business-name]/[business-id], calculate total page view of all 24 urls , and then return just one result with page view is total page view of all 24 urls.

How can i do it ?
Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to test your request?

Comment: @Blexy: Yes , i tried

Comment: download all the data to Excel, remove the parameters manually and then do a simple pivot table.